# Firebase and AppStore validation => Advertising

Tags: firebase, app-store, analytics, appstore-approval, ads

I'm going to submit my app to the AppStore and this is the first time I'm using Firebase in order to register analytics.
I only used Firebase/Core but there is still Advertising info in the POD :

```
grep -r advertisingIdentifier .
Binary file     ./Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics matches
```

And :

> The AdSupport Framework is not currently linked.

I already got some apps refused because of Advertising using GoogleAnalytics, should I worry using Firebase and submitting my application ? Have you ever been rejected because of this ? Do you have any advice to prevent a rejection ?

Thanks.

Comment: I submitted with "No IDFA" on Itunes Connect but I think this is wrong since there is the word "advertisingIdentifier".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because app store submission policy is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/65839) and better addressed by [Apple support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/65839).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok validation has passed with "NO" for IDFA